Conectar checador ZKteco con PHP
estoy intentando conectarme a un checador ZKTeco K40 por medio de ZKlib de php, estoy usando un código que descargue de github el cual se puede descargar de este enlace:  https://github.com/vodvud/php_zklib
modifique la dirección IP a la que tengo en el checador, instale composer en mi computadora, pero aún no encuentro porque no conecta, quite la contraseña del checador, no encuentro algo que me pueda orientar un poco, dejo el código que estoy usando:
    $enableGetDeviceInfo = true;
    $enableGetUsers = true;
    $enableGetData = true;

    include('zklib/ZKLib.php');

    $zk = new ZKLib(
        '192.168.2.204' //your device IP
    );

    $ret = $zk->connect();
    
    var_dump($ret);

El vardump que tengo me retorna false, también habilite algunas extensiones en el php.ini que son estas
extension=soap
extension=sockets
extension=php_sockets.dll

Agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar

Tenes que revisar que la IP del checkeador ZKTeco K40 (192.168.2.204) esté en la misma red que tu PC. Probá un ping a la IP 192.168.2.204.
El puerto predeterminado de comunicación para dispositivos ZKTeco es el 4370, hacele un telnet al puerto para verificarlo
telnet 192.168.2.204 4370

Si no te podes conectar puede ser un firewall.
Las extensiones estan habilitadas? Si usas lin, fijate extension=sockets en windows > php_sockets.dll
Si el problema persiste, actualiza las dependencias con esto:
composer update

Podes modificar tu codigo agregando el puerto, de esta forma:
$enableGetDeviceInfo = true;
$enableGetUsers = true;
$enableGetData = true;

include('zklib/ZKLib.php');

$zk = new ZKLib(
    '192.168.2.204', 4370  
);

$ret = $zk->connect();

if ($ret) {
    echo "Conectado correctamente";
} else {
    echo "No se pudo conectar. Verifica la IP o el puerto.";
}

Saludos.
